# Datagrid Binding TextBox Memory Leak

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, datagrid

I red many articles about datagrid leaking, and couldn't find right way.
Here is some code to reproduce. It has datagrid and buttoon, each time you press button, it fills table with random numbers, and takes 10mb of memory, and doesn't release it.
Binding to TextBlock doesn't cause memory leak, but i need textbox two way binding.

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Name="dg" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text0}"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text1}"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text2}"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text3}"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text4}"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text5}"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text6}"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text7}"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text8}"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text9}"></TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="update" Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

```
namespace test
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    public ObservableCollection<obj> res;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        res = new ObservableCollection<obj>();


        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            res.Add(new obj
            {
                Text0 = ((new Random()).NextDouble() * 100).ToString(),
                Text1 = ((new Random()).NextDouble() * 100).ToString(),
                Text2 = ((new Random()).NextDouble() * 100).ToString(),
                Text3 = ((new Random()).NextDouble() * 100).ToString(),
                Text4 = ((new Random()).NextDouble() * 100).ToString(),
                Text5 = ((new Random()).NextDouble() * 100).ToString(),
                Text6 = ((new Random()).NextDouble() * 100).ToString(),
                Text7 = ((new Random()).NextDouble() * 100).ToString(),
                Text8 = ((new Random()).NextDouble() * 100).ToString(),
                Text9 = ((new Random()).NextDouble() * 100).ToString(),
            });
        }
        dg.DataContext = res;
    }


}
public class obj : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string text0;
    public string Text0
    {
        get
        {
            return text0;
        }
        set
        {
            text0 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Text0");
        }
    }
    private string text1;
    public string Text1
    {
        get
        {
            return text1;
        }
        set
        {
            text1 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Text1");
        }
    }
    private string text2;
    public string Text2
    {
        get
        {
            return text2;
        }
        set
        {
            text2 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Text2");
        }
    }
    private string text3;
    public string Text3
    {
        get
        {
            return text3;
        }
        set
        {
            text3 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Text3");
        }
    }
    private string text4;
    public string Text4
    {
        get
        {
            return text4;
        }
        set
        {
            text4 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Text4");
        }
    }
    private string text5;
    public string Text5
    {
        get
        {
            return text5;
        }
        set
        {
            text5 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Text5");
        }
    }
    private string text6;
    public string Text6
    {
        get
        {
            return text6;
        }
        set
        {
            text6 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Text6");
        }
    }
    private string text7;
    public string Text7
    {
        get
        {
            return text7;
        }
        set
        {
            text7 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Text7");
        }
    }
    private string text8;
    public string Text8
    {
        get
        {
            return text8;
        }
        set
        {
            text8 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Text8");
        }
    }
    private string text9;
    public string Text9
    {
        get
        {
            return text9;
        }
        set
        {
            text9 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Text9");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

}

Comment: I just profiled your test app and is not leaking on Windows 7 with .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can use DataGridTextColumn instead of DataGridTemplateColumn your memory will not leak.

dunno why DataGridTemplateColumn has a memoryleak

edit:

i would also init OberservableColletion just once, set the datacontext just once  and use clear in the button_click.

EDIT: the memoryleak problem with DataGridTemplateColumn seems to be gone with .NET4.5

Comment: >OberservableColletion just once, set the datacontext just once and use clear - doesn't help

Comment: ou, yep. but in my app, ia need to have some checkboxes in some rows, and etc. because of that i used template with template selector. Can i make it with textcolumn?

Comment: there is also a checkboxcolumn

Comment: i have diffrenet controls in one column. because of that i need template

Comment: maybe you can send a bug report to microsoft and get some helpful infoprmation for your DataGridTemplateColumn problem

Answer (score 1):

`TextBox` in WPF has a `Undo` \ `Redo` stack associated with it and it stores redoable / undoable values as they change to new ones. So may be that explains the **unreleased** memory for TextBoxes.

Now you may ask is you are setting `ItemsSource` fresh each time. Isnt that supposed to regenerate new `TextBoxes` (so that newly generated `TextBox` has no chance of holding any **old** `Undo` Stack). I guess `Datagrid` recycles `ItemsContainer` and reuses the generated `TextBoxes`.

But thats just my speculation!!!

You can try restricting the `Undo` stack & recheck if it works for you ...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/376f7765-1c70-4289-a59b-e27c168a0fa2

Comment: This is standard behavior of TextBox, the leak was present in 3.5. In 4.0 the memory will be released when and if necessary. I don't think it's a leak at all.

Comment: On windows xp sp3, it becomes to 500mb, and application hangs:(

Comment: Is it your machine's WPF setup? can you try any other `ItemsControl` like `ListView` with `TextBox` Template Column. How does that behave?

Comment: Yes, ListView also cause this huge memory consumption. So i found workaround, EditingCellTemplate with TextBox, and CellTemplate with TextBlock. Seems it work stable, and doesn't eat memory. What do you think?

Comment: Yes so that way, what blindmeis suggested above makes sense. Plz accept his/her answer.